# Cannot read attribute of null using array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string, loops

I am trying to change the the classes of element that already exist but are hidden . This problem is whenever the code is executed a null exception is thrown. Tried everything but can't seem to get what's wrong

```
function changeMenu(code) {
    var i, id = ["'demo'", "'drill'", "'alert'"];
    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i += 1) {
        if (document.getElementById(id[i]) !== null) {
            if (i !== code) {
                document.getElementById(id[i]).setAttribute('class', 'row hidden');
            } else {
                document.getElementById(id[i]).setAttribute('class', 'row');
            }
        } else {window.alert("error");}
    }
}
```

The script is already loaded in the end of document and the id also exists.

Comment: there are both " and ' in your array declaration? is this an error ?

Comment: @JacobGoh ' ' is just used to avoid using escape characters since getElementById accept the element id in quotes

Comment: Where would you need to escape or unescape anything in the code above?

Comment: It accepts a string. Not `element id in quotes`. A string can be 'abc' or "abc". it's the same for `getElementById `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are storing the ids with the `'` in your strings, so when you will call `document.getElementById("'demo'")` it won't find the element and return `null`.

Change your `id` array declaration to:

```
var i, id = ["demo", "drill", "alert"];
```

> The script is already loaded in the end of document and the id also exists.

Yes the id exists but they don't have `'` on it, just remove it from your array.

Comment: You are welcome, it happens, just keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with quotes and tests

I believe you actually meant to do this:

```js
var ids = ["demo", "drill", "alert"];
function changeMenu(code) {
  for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    var elm = document.getElementById(id[i]);
    if (elm) { // element exists
      elm.classList.toggle("hidden",ids[i] !== code);
    } 
    else {
      window.alert("error");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This method is a lot efficient then mine's beginner one, However I have a question in 'if (elm)' how elm will be treated as a Boolean or null is also considered false

Comment: undefined, null, empty, 0 are all falsy.